# Spring Boot @GetMapping to a URL ending with .jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mustache

We have a URL that has to end with (customer requirement) something like /test.jsp.

Now that we're finally running Spring Boot (2.1.1.RELEASE), we would like to ditch JSP and use some templating engine, in this case Mustache. I have a controller mapping like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestController  {

    @GetMapping(path = "/test.jsp")
    public ModelAndView test(...) {...}
}
```

This just doesn't work. I have

> spring.mvc.pathmatch.use-suffix-pattern=true

In our application.properties, anything spring.mvc.view-related is commented out, when I add another mapping with just /test, it works for /test. Funny thing is I have managed to get the same exact thing working when using Spring MVC and Thymeleaf but I can't seem to find the difference.

Additionally, I added a test for this like so:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class TestTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        final MockHttpServletRequestBuilder testRequestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/test.jsp");

        MvcResult responseResult = mockMvc.perform(testRequestBuilder).andReturn();


        response = responseResult.getResponse();
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), equalTo(HttpStatus.OK.value()));
    }

}
```

This works fine, the content of the response is also exactly what I want. The test profile is the same as the one when using mvn spring-boot:run for the time being.

Anyone got an idea on how to get this working? Thanks!

Comment: It's weird to directly call a jsp via the URL. But if you really have to, you might get it done using a path `/` and a path variable. Like `@GetMapping(path = "/{jsp}")` and then have controller argument `@PathVariable final String jsp` and check if it's `test.jsp`?

Comment: Could you please complete your test method body. I think there is a problem with spring.mustache.prefix & spring.mustache.suffix for SpringBoot to find proper template file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it - I had everything working including test.html, test.xml, test.wasd and test. So I figured it couldn't be Spring by itself. After some debugging in various Tomcat classes I found the culprit: JspServlet was somehow present in the classpath and being automatically configured, originating from

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Removing the dependency led to test.jsp being recognized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The dot is probably being truncated. or escaped.
You can probably do something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/{pageName:.+}")   
public void test(
  @PathVariable("pageName") String pageName) {
     if(pageName.equals("test.jsp")) {
                   //...
}
```

I know you dont exactly want a variable, but just throwing an idea

Comment: Doesn't work as well. test. followed by anything but jsp works, jsp doesn't.