# Spring boot web app with jsp file extension in the url

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, model-view-controller

We have a legacy web app that uses the url below:

`https://example.com/forms/forms.jsp`

We have rewritten the legacy code to use spring boot web app with the url `https://example.com/forms` without `.jsp` extension in the url.

In order to keep the old url, which is a business requirement, I followed this [Spring MVC @PathVariable with a dot (.) gets truncated](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-pathvariable-dot). However, it only works when there is a `/` `https://example.com/forms/forms.jsp/` in the url.

I googled it, found some suggestions in stack overflow and tried a couple of different approaches. But not quite working.

UPDATES:

I just found [this post on jsp in the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595497/spring-boot-getmapping-to-a-url-ending-with-jsp). I updated from `@GetMapping("/forms/{jspName:.+}")` to `@GetMapping(path = "/forms/{jspName:.+}")`. This made it possible to check the pathVariable in the if statement. However, the `return` statement does not return the expected `forms.jsp` file as before; instead it gives `404` error.

url : http://localhost:8080/forms/forms.jsp

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/forms/{jspName:.+}")
    public String getForms(@PathVariable("jspName") String jspName) {
        if (jspName.equalsIgnoreCase("forms.jsp")) {
            log.debug("JSP file is {}", jspName);
            return "forms";
        }
        return "index";
    }
```

Console:

```
[nio-8080-exec-1] c.n.e.c.EthicsEmailFormController        : JSP file is forms.jsp
```

404 Error:

```
No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/forms/forms.jsp
HTTP ERROR 404
```

application.properties - The `forms.jsp` is stored under `/WEB-INF/views/page/forms.jsp`.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/page/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

For comparison:

Below works when the url is `https://example.com/forms/forms.jsp/` with a `/` at the end of the url. But the existing url (that is specified in the requirement) does not contain a `/` at the end of the url. It has to be `https://example.com/forms/forms.jsp`.

```
    @GetMapping("/forms/{jspName:.+}")
    public String getForms(@PathVariable("jspName") String jspName) {
        log.debug("Jsp file name = {} ", jspName);
        return "forms";
    }
```

I saw some suggestion is to remove below dependency. I also do NOT have below dependency in `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since this app is for training only, I moved the jsp file to `webapp/forms.forms.jsp` folder. This way, the jsp file can be accessed directly from the url below:

```
https://example.com/forms/forms.jsp
```

There is no need to go through a controller. Thanks to my friend Barry for his suggestion. Thanks!